# Raspberry pi: can't share file using NFS

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-14.04, mount, nfs

I can't share files between my desktop (as an NFS server, os: ubuntu 14.04) and my Rasberry pi (as NFS client, os: Raspbian jessie)

what I did is the following:

**Server Side**

```
apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
mkdir -p /export/egmintel
mount --bind /home/egmintel /export/egmintel
```

In /etc/default/nfs-kernel-server :  NEED_SVCGSSD="no"

In /etc/idmapd.conf in both client and server:

```
[Mapping]

Nobody-User = nobody
Nobody-Group = nogroup
```

In /etc/exports

```
/export       192.168.1.48(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
/export/egmintel 192.168.1.48(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
```

192.168.1.48 is my raspberry pi address, the nfs client.
Then I restarted the nfs server:

```
service nfs-kernel-server restart
```

**Client side:**
nfs-common is installed:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install nfs-common 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nfs-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
```

time out when I try the mount command:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o proto=tcp,port=2049 192.168.1.78:/ shareIntel
```

Note: I have KURA installed on my Raspberry pi and I have opened the ports: 2049/tcp, 32771/tcp, 892/udp

I dont know what have I missed to not be able to share files using NFS between my destop and my Raspberry pi.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I had the firewall set on my desktop.